# Spring context can not be loaded in Spock test method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spock

Hi I have a Spring Boot (2.1.6 RELEASE) application, and I am trying add some simple integration test to my app. 
Firstly I've create a base IntegrationTest class like below:

```
@TypeChecked
@Transactional
@Rollback
@SpringBootTest(classes = AppRunner.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
abstract class IntegrationTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper

    MockMvc mockMvc

    @Before
    void setupMockMvc() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build()
    }

    protected ResultActions makePost(final String uri, final Object dto) {
        mockMvc.perform(post(uri)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                    .content(dtoToJson(dto))
        )
    }

    private String dtoToJson(final Object dto) {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dto)
    }
}
```

This is my test method:

```
class TestForTest extends IntegrationTest {


    @WithMockUser(username = "xxx@gmail.com")
    def "should reset password and send mail with proper activation link"() {
        given:
            def email = "user2@xxx.com"
        when:
            ResultActions result = makePost("/rest/user/resendActivationMail", email)
        then:
            1 == 1
            println(result)
    }
}
```

Is strange because I have feeling the context was not be loaded, and so more there was no any try to do this.

I got error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required

```
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder.<init>(DefaultMockMvcBuilder.java:52)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(MockMvcBuilders.java:51)
at pl.isolution.veolia.mveolia.spec.IntegrationTest.setupMockMvc(IntegrationTest.groovy:37)
```

Is there is a problem with Maven or IntellijIDEA? This took abot 340 ms, and I didn't see any attempt of context loading.

My stack:
JAVA 11, Maven 3, Spring Boot 2.1.6, Spock 1.3-groovy-2.5

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Ok What a shame :) I missed a dependency.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: That was what I have suspected ;)